# No page found 'sidepanel.jelly' for class hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkResult

Tags: jenkins, testlink

I'm try to see the Testlink report in Jenkins getting this. Help me to fix this.

A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.

```
Stack trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/Users/di-engg/.jenkins/plugins/testlink/WEB-INF/lib/testlink.jar!/hudson/plugins/testlink/TestLinkResult/index.jelly:6:57: <st:include> No page found 'sidepanel.jelly' for class hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkResult
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:127)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:735)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:686)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$13.dispatch(MetaClass.java:411)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$13.dispatch(MetaClass.java:411)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:44)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.provideRequestDuring(ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.java:106)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.doFilter(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:44)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:129)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/Users/di-engg/.jenkins/plugins/testlink/WEB-INF/lib/testlink.jar!/hudson/plugins/testlink/TestLinkResult/index.jelly:6:57: <st:include> No page found 'sidepanel.jelly' for class hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkResult
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
```